# Using different stringbuilder objects to create one spreadsheet

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-services, c#-4.0

I currently have an application that generates reports from a Web Service. The reports are basically tables of data which are being pulled from a database by the WebService (using a stored procedure).

The first 50 records are displayed on the screen (sent to the view) but there is also a button that the user can click which downloads the entire query to an excel spreadsheet. This is achieved by passing the results of the query into a model and then writing that to a stringbuilder, which is used to create the spreadsheet. The code for this action method is as follows:

```
// WebService call
var reportResult = SubscriberService.GetReport(reportName, criteria.CurrentPageNumber - 1, 0, getReportParameters(model.GroupId, criteria));
  model.Result = getModel(reportResult);     

  // if file name is not ended with .csv we there it as prefix and file will be prefix_{date}.csv
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) || fileName.LastIndexOf(".csc", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != fileName.Length - 4)
    fileName = string.Format("{0}_{1}.csv", fileName, DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());

  HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
  HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);

  if (model.Result != null)
  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    exportRowHeader(sb);
    HttpContext.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
    sb.Clear();

    foreach (var item in model.Result.Members)
    {
      exportRowData(sb, model.Result, item);
      HttpContext.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
      sb.Clear();
    }
    HttpContext.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
  }
  else
  {
    HttpContext.Response.Write(ReportResources.Report_Exporting_NoDataAvailable);
  }

  HttpContext.Response.Flush();
```

My problem here is that for large queries the communication with the Web Serivce takes too long and times out. There is also an issue with the maximum amount of data that can be sent via the WebService.

So what I was thinking of doing is to break up the WebService calls. The WebService has the ability to paginate the results that it sends back. So I'd basically call 200 results at a time (until all the results have been returned).

Is this possible to do by simply creating additional stringbuilder objects and then combining them all together to make one spreadsheet of results? Would this lead to memory issues?

If this doesn't seem possible can you suggest an alternative solution?

Comment: StringBUilder has an Append method that receive a string to append to the previous content. So I think you could work on this. The webservice could also be of help having a method that gives back the size required to recieve all the informations so you could size your base stringbuilder from the start without implicit resizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work in the end fairly painlessly by using a do-while loop. There doesn't appear to be any memory issues with holding all of this in the HttpContext.Response although it took 3 and a half minutes to create a spreadsheet with 72,000 rows and 25 columns:

```
int pageNum = 0;
  int pageSize = 2000;




  // if file name is not ended with .csv we there it as prefix and file will be prefix_{date}.csv
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) || fileName.LastIndexOf(".csc", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != fileName.Length - 4)
    fileName = string.Format("{0}_{1}.csv", fileName, DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());

  HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
  HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);

  do
  {

    var reportResult = SubscriberService.GetReport(reportName, pageNum, pageSize,
                                                   getReportParameters(model.GroupId, criteria));
    model.Result = getModel(reportResult);

    if (model.Result != null)
    {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

      if (pageNum == 0)
      {
        exportRowHeader(sb);
        HttpContext.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
        sb.Clear();
      }

      foreach (var item in model.Result.Members)
      {
        exportRowData(sb, model.Result, item);
        HttpContext.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
        sb.Clear();
      }
      HttpContext.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
      HttpContext.Response.Write(ReportResources.Report_Exporting_NoDataAvailable);
      break;
    }

    pageNum++;

  } while (model.Result.Members.Count==pageSize); 

  HttpContext.Response.Flush();
```